# how to resize another window not belong to my program by using MFC?

Tags: mfc

I need write a program to resize other program's windows,

what I know is their HWND, How can I do it?

I'm trying this:

```
CWnd *pWnd = CWnd::FromHandle(handle);
pWnd->MoveWindow(x,y,w,h);
```

Comment: looks like I solved this question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That sends a wm_poschanged, a wm_move and a wm_size to the other window. If that other window explicitly doesn't respond to those messages, then your attempt won't work.

Also note that messaging between different integrity level apps (such as yours and explorer, say) is very limited under Vista/W7. [This S.O. question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542675/access-to-external-window-handles) may therefore be relevant to you.